# Проблема импорта в Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Начал изучать программирование с Python. В качестве редактора выбрал vscode, создал виртуальную среду, где будут храниться файлы, но возникла проблема с импортом. Ошибка:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'

хотя я установил этот модуль в виртуальную среду через pip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи, спасибо

Comment: Внизу слева на панели статуса нужно нажать на название интерпретатора и выбрать интерпретатор из виртуального окружения

Comment: там не было интерпретатора виртуального окружения, но поискав в интернете, нашел решение Нужно в файле settings.json прописать "python.pythonPath": "путь к интерпретатору", который находится в папке виртаульного окружения проекта bin/python - в моем случае, python3.8, после этого все сторонние пакеты, загруженные через virtualenv стали видны. Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: Если открыть в редакторе конкретно папку с проектом, в которой уже находится папка виртуального окружения, то интерпретатор из виртуального окружения в том списке сам появится, ничего прописывать не нужно будет.